# mp3 player using winmm, event mp3 end

Tags: c#, mp3

I find some code and modify it for my own purpose. But I don't know how to hook when mp3 reach the end. I want do if one songs end, next is playing. Playing random song when current end it's simple, but how to know when it's end? Should I try calculate length of song and use timer to call function when the song ends?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;

namespace Playing_MP3_songs
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public const int MM_MCINOTIFY = 0x3B9;
        [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
        private static extern long mciSendString(string strCommand, StringBuilder strReturn, int iReturnLength, IntPtr hwndCallback);

        List<string> lista;
        List<string> lista2;
        string st;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


        }

        private void set_list()
        {
            string[] costam = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, "*.mp3", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            string[] costam2 = new string[Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, "*.mp3", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count()];
            int ilosc = costam.Count();
            int x = 0;
            while (x <= ilosc - 1)
            {
                costam2[x] = Path.GetFileName(costam[x]);
                x++;

            }
            lista = new List<string>(costam);
            lista2 = new List<string>(costam2);
            //listBox1.Sorted = true;
            listBox2.DataSource = lista;
            listBox1.DataSource = lista2;
            if (listBox1.Items.Count == 0)
            {
                button2.Enabled = false;
                button3.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                button2.Enabled = false;
                button3.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                set_list();
                button3.Enabled = true; //So you dont play no file. lol
            }


        }


        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {

            base.OnLoad(e);
            TextReader sr = new StreamReader("path.txt");
            st = sr.ReadLine();
            sr.Close();
            folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = st;
            set_list();
        }
        protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnClosing(e);
            TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("path.txt");
            writer.WriteLine(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
            writer.Close();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            stop();
            listBox2.SetSelected(listBox1.SelectedIndex, true);
            mciSendString("open \"" + listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() + "\" type mpegvideo alias MediaFile", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
            mciSendString("play MediaFile", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

            //button3.Enabled = false;
            button2.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void play()
        {
            stop();
            listBox2.SetSelected(listBox1.SelectedIndex, true);
            mciSendString("open \"" + listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() + "\" type mpegvideo alias MediaFile", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
            mciSendString("play MediaFile", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
            //button3.Enabled = false;
            button2.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void stop()
        {
            mciSendString("close MediaFile", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
            listBox2.ClearSelected();
            //button2.Enabled = false;
            button3.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            mciSendString("close MediaFile", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
            listBox2.ClearSelected();
            button2.Enabled = false;
            button3.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void listBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar.ToString() == "B")
            {
                listBox1.ClearSelected();
                int ilosc = listBox1.Items.Count;
                Random random = new Random();
                int number = random.Next(0, ilosc - 1);
                listBox1.SetSelected(number, true);
                stop();
                play();
                e.Handled = true;
            }

        }

        private void listBox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            play();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Append `notify` to `play MediaFile` command:

```
mciSendString("play MediaFile notify", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Override the WndProc function in the form, to receive the notify message when the playback complete

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == Media.MM_MCINOTIFY)
    {
        do smthing..
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```